# Issues with logging to G-mail with Mechanize

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, mechanize, http-status-code-405

I made this Python program and it behaves like this : it fills the user name and password field for gmail .(I want it to login to my gmail account via mechanize).
The code is :

```
import re 
from mechanize import Browser
def main():
    br = Browser()

    # Ignore robots.txt
    br.set_handle_robots( False )
    # Google demands a user-agent that isn't a robot
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

    # Retrieve the Google home page, saving the response
    br.open( "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en&                                         continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail&service=mail&    flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession" )

    # Select the search box and search for 'foo'

    br.select_form( nr=0 )
    br["identifier"] = 'mygmail'
    br.submit()
    br.select_form( nr=0 )
    br["password"]="mypassword"
    # Get the search results
    br.submit()
    print(br.text)
main()
```

but I get the following error:

> mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 405: HTTP
>   method POST is not supported by this URL

Why and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Isn't it easier to log in to pop or imap?

Comment: I actually want to use mechanize.

Comment: Python mechanize has been dead for a long time. You won't find good support here.